# How to deal with 2-step authentication for Facebook on Spotify login?

Tags: ios, spotify, facebook-login, cocoalibspotify-2.0

I've integrated the cocoalibspotify framework into my application, and at some point I ask the user to log in to Spotify. The login view controller presents a Facebook login, but does not switch to the Facebook application.

However, I have tested this with a friend's account that has 2-step authentication enabled for Facebook (where Facebook sends him a code to his mobile phone for completely logging in).

Spotify doesn't seem to have a two-step process for logging in for these types of Facebook accounts. Spotify just returns saying "wrong credentials".

Am I missing something, or is two-step Facebook log in not possible through Spotify?

Or is there a different way to log in a user that has 2-step auth enabled on their Facebook account?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you try to login 3 or 4 times, then facebook very helpfully gives you an "account alert" on their website and lets you verify that you were actually trying to login and then it should work.

I'm not sure about the better way to do this. Two factor auth still trips up even many of google's login mechanisms that don't even involve oauth.

Comment: Indeed, Facebook did seem to pop-up a notification eventually, but it only notified us that something tried to log in to Facebook without 2-factor authentication. I didn't see any way to add/allow my application as one that is supported to *just* log in directly.